# Increase \chapter{Title} horizontal margins

Tags: formatting, chapters

I am writing my dissertation and I am requested to write the chapter titles as inverted pyramids.
Because of the specific margins I have on the format I am using and because of the specific words I have in one title, I am not able to make it.
How can I force the margins of one chapter title only to be a little wider?

This is my title:

```
\chapter{Effects of Irradiance and Ambient Temperature on a Decision-Making\\Tool for Rooftop PV Array Sizing\\ for Commercial Buildings}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What class are you using? The standard `book` class typesets chapter titles ragged right, which is difficult to make inverted pyramids with.

Comment: I am using a customized class from my university. The title is actually centered.

Comment: Without some detail about the class, it's impossible to help

Comment: If your university wants pyramidal chapter titles and they supply the class, then they should modify the class so that the results suit their demands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the title inside a centred box using `\makebox[\linewidth]` and stack it using `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{geometry} % Just for this example
\geometry{
  paper = a3paper,
  landscape,
  showframe
}

\begin{document}

\chapter[ToC title]
  {\makebox[\linewidth]{\begin{tabular}{ c }
    Effects of Irradiance and Ambient Temperature on a Decision-Making \\
              Tool for Rooftop PV Array Sizing                         \\
                 for Commercial Buildings
    \end{tabular}}
  }

\end{document}
```